# How can you get 125 from 2,3,4,5,6?

Tags: formation-of-numbers

You are allowed to use the four standard operations (+-/*) to get 125, using each of the following digits exactly once: 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.

I came up with an answer, but took me a while; curious to see what you all come up with!

Comment: Until I saw that you could only use the basic operators, I had $5^{4\times 6\div 2^3}$

Comment: If there was a $1$, then I would have used $4^3 + 6\times 5\times 2 + 1$

Comment: Or, if we were also allowed to concatenate and use powers, then I would have done $(6 + 3)^2 + 4||5 - 1$

Comment: Or I could just be simple if there really was a $1$ and just do $2\times 3\times 4\times 5 + 6 - 1$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In case brackets are not allowed

> $2 + 3 + 4 * 5 * 6$

Comment: Very nice - and I think you're probably right that brackets aren't allowed (in the original problem), so this is probably the best answer.

Comment: not only no brackets, but in the order given, well done

Answer (score 8):

Here's an answer that I get:

> $$6\times4\times(2+3) + 5=125$$

Comment: That's actually easier than the one I came up with :D

Comment: How come you didn't notice you could exchange 2+3 and 5 to avoid parenthesis? ;)

Answer (score 8):

> $$(6\times4+3-2)\times5 = 125$$

Answer (score 3):

All earlier provided are disciplined answers. Here is an undisciplined one

> (23 * 5) + 4 + 6, that is 115 + 10 = 125. This is undisciplined as it used concatenation of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Hope I'm not late (or wrong).

> 6*5*4+3+2

Comment: Except for reversing the order, this is identical to the accepted answer, which was posted 18 hours earlier.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry about that. I honestly didn't peek at the previous two answers that had been posted before mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one's different than the other answers:

> $(6 * 5 + 2) * 4 - 3 = 32 * 4 - 3 = 128 - 3 = 125$

You can avoid brackets with [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation):

> 6 5 * 2 + 4 * 3 -